# CSS Animation Delay Not Working with angular and scss - staggering effect

Tags: css, angular, animation, sass, delay

I'm trying to achieve the staggering effect using animation delay from below article.

https://css-tricks.com/writing-animations-that-bring-your-site-to-life/

Having trouble finding out the mistake I'm making during writing scss code. Animation is working but the delay is not getting applied to the elements.

Firstly I thought the *ngFor is the issue as the element not present until data comes. Hence commented the ng for and trying with static boxes. Still no luck.

If anyone able to pinpoint the root cause why the animation delay is not getting applied, it will be really helpful.

**tracks.component.html**

```
<div class="bg-dark vh-100">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row pt-5">
      <div class="col-2">
        <img src="../../../assets/images/artists/{{artist.image}}" width="100%" height="100%" id="artist" class="image ml-5">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tracks">
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="offset-1"></div>
          <!--<div class="col-2" *ngFor="let track of recentList";>
            <img src="../../../assets/images/tracks/recent/{{track.image}}" class="track">
          </div>-->
          <div class="col-2 mr-3">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="track"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mr-3">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="track"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mr-3">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="track"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mr-3">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="track"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-2 mr-3">
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 300px; height: 300px;" class="track"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-container bg-white w-100">
      <div class="track-list">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-7">
            <div *ngFor="let track of recentList">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-5">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**tracks.component.scss**

```
:root {
  --translate: '';
}

@keyframes move-image {
  from {
    transform: var(--translate);
  }
}

.image {
  animation: move-image 0.6s;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.tracks {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes move-track-container {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.track-container{
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  height: 670px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  animation: move-track-container 0.7s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes scale-down {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: none;
  }
}

.tracks{
  .track{
    border-radius: 5%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 5px #00000014;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-30%);
    animation: scale-down 1s ease forwards;
  }
}



@for $i from 1 through 5 {
 track:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    animation-delay:(#{$i*0.1s});
  }
}
```

**tracks.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
// @ts-ignore
import tracksList from '../../../assets/json data/tracks.json';
import {trigger, query, stagger, animate, style, keyframes, transition} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracks',
  templateUrl: './tracks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracks.component.scss']
})
export class TracksComponent implements OnInit {

  artistsList:any[];
  tracksList:any[];
  recentList:any[];
  artist:any;
  @ViewChild('artistImage') artistImage;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.tracksList = tracksList;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log('x and y',this.artist.positionX +' and '+this.artist.positionY);
    const offsetLeft = 100;
    const offsetTop = 30;
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
      '--translate',
      `translate(${this.artist.positionX - offsetLeft}px, ${this.artist.positionY - offsetTop}px) scale(0.792)`
    )
    console.log('this.recentList',this.recentList);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.artist = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(map=>window.history.state.artist);
    this.artist = {
      category: "Pop singer",
      id: 2,
      image: "sukhe.jpg",
      name: "Sukh E",
      positionX: 335,
      positionY: 48
    }
    this.recentList = this.tracksList[this.artist.id].recent;
  }

}
```

[image]